# Как правильно добавлять переменные в запросе?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть **SearchModel**, есть запрос `$query = Table::find();`
С фронтенда в переменную `$name` приходят данные и это нужно добавить в запрос.

```
if($this->name) {
  $query->andWhere("MATCH(name) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)", [':query' => str_replace(' ', '*', trim($this->name)) . '*']);
}
```

Как я понимаю, такой формат не правильный, может быть "дыра" в безопасности.

Как безопасно вставлять переменные с данными в запрос?

Comment: это безопасный способ

Comment: Если ввести @, то "падает" система

Comment: она падает потому что у вас сам запрос корявый

Comment: addslashes($name) - Returns a string with backslashes added before characters that need to be escaped. Ну будет проблем если добавить single quote ```'```